# Differentiating between queue full and queue empty

Tags: c

I am using a an array with a write index and a read index to implement a straightforward FIFO Queue. I do the usual MOD ArraySize when incrementing the write and read index. 
Is there a way to differentiate between queue full and queue empty condition (wrIndex == rdIndex) without using any additional queuecount and also without wasting any array entry i.e . Queue is full if (WrIndex + 1 ) MOD ArraySize == ReadIndex

Comment: The program runs on an embedded processor with 16Kb memory and bear metal (no OS). Writing the code in C is a luxury . Dont think it is premature optimization.

Comment: the 4 bytes you need for an int is just not worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with 'wasting' an array entry to detect the queue full condition, especially if you're dealing with different threads/tasks being producers and consumers. Having another flag keep track of that situation increases the locking necessary to keep things consistent and increases the likelihood of some sort of bug that introduces a race condition. This is even more true in the case where you can't use a critical section (as you mention in a comment) to ensure that things are in-sync.

You'll need at least a bit somewhere to keep track of that condition, and that probably means at least a byte.  Assuming that your queue contains `ints` you're only saving 3 bytes of RAM and you're going to chew up several more bytes of program image (which might not be as precious, so that might not matter). If you keep a flag bit inside a byte used to store other flag bits, then you have to additionally deal with setting/testing/clearing that flag bit in a thread safe manner to ensure that the other bits don't get corrupted.

If you're queuing bytes, then you probably save nothing - you can consider the sentinel element to be the flag that you'd have to put somewhere else. But now you have to have *no* extra code to deal with the flag.

Consider carefully if you really need that extra queue item, and keep in mind that if you're queuing bytes, then the extra queue item probably isn't really extra space

Comment: Thanks for the detailed trade off analysis.  Code size increase is a concern . I measured the total memory consumption and the 'wasting' entry approach actually saves total memory footprint by about 32 bytes compared to any other approach suggested. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a read and write index, you could use a read index and a queue count. From the queue count, you can easily tell if the queue is empty of full. And the write index can be computed as (read index + queue count) mod array_size.

Comment: While this could be made to work, it will require more complex code (which takes more bytes of storage) than simple `in` and `out` pointers.

Comment: This is a neat idea . Unfortunately I still have the issue with requiring critical section which is not possible. Thanks for the idea .Surely plenty of places that this can be used.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with a queue count?  It sounds like you're going for maximum efficiency and minimal logic, and while I would do the same, I think I'd still use a queue count variable.  Otherwise, one other potential solution would be to use a linked list.  Low memory usage, and removing first element would be easy, just make sure that you have pointers to the head and tail of the list.

Comment: and yes, this does sound like a symptom of trying to optimize too soon...  When in doubt, follow this order: 1) Make it work  2) Make it pretty/clean  3) Make it fast

Answer (score 0):

Basically you only need a single additional bit somewhere to signal that the queue is currently empty. You can probably stash that away somewhere, e.g., in the most significant bit of one of your indices (and than AND-ing the lower bits creatively in places where you need to work only on the actual index into your array).

But honestly, I'd go with a queue count first and only cut that if I really need that space, instead of putting up with bit fiddling.

Comment: I cant use queue count because the data structure can get into an inconsistent state whereby index may be incremented but count may not be updated before which an interrupt can occur. There is a an atomic increment statement but I cant use critical sections due to hard real time interrupt latency requirement.

Comment: The idea of using a bit to indicate queue fullness is good and I will try it. The processor supports bit band aliasing which is interrupt safe. If I dont get any better answers will accept your answer

Comment: @Badri: even with bit-banding you'll have problems if you can't use critical sections because you need to keep the indexes and the bitflag in sync atomically.